# Search for a value in a column which is equal to cell value in another sheet, then copy paste to new location

Tags: vba, excel

I need to search column R in sheet 2 for the integer value from sheet 1 Cell A1. Then need to copy 20 cells along row sheet 2, then paste to cell G8 sheet 2. 
I've tried this code but don't know what to enter in the `Find(What:=`
or copy bits

```
Columns("R:R").Select
    Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="??????", After:=ActiveCell,  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Assuming "Sheet1" is the name of the sheet you need.

The exact requirements for copy paste is not clear. Here is generic code to perform copy/paste operations:

Example: Copy/paste from cell B1 to B2:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
```

OR simply,

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
```

`Sheets("Sheet1").` part in the code is needed if you are referring to sheets other than the currently active sheet. If you are working within the curently active sheet only, then this part can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks slayernoah, you got me out of a corner! this is exactly what I needed.